# About Asking Ambiguous Question

Tags: discussion, feature-request

### IMPORTANT EDIT

**IT SEEMS DISCUSSION CAN ALREADY BE DONE IN CHAT. I JUST REALISED THIS BECAUSE I HAD JUST GET 20 REP TODAY. MOD MAY CLOSE THIS IMIDIATELY**

Sometimes, we visit stackexchange to ask question that we does not know or wonder what the answer is. However, more often than not, I am asking question without knowing whether an exact answer is available; thus, causing me to **accidentally** make 'opinion-based' question followed by a bunch of vote down.

I always thought that this is somewhat unfair.
"What will happen to this and that?" -- Vote down -2 rep. Vote down -2 rep. "HEY THAT IS OPINION BASED YOU ARE WRRRRONGK! GTFO from this 'fact' site!"

However, I argued that if we note down facts related to my question we can narrow down possibility and guess what will be more appropriate.

**So, it seems the site is somewhat 'aggressive' and makes me sad :(**

---

Now, in order to avoid that, I think we can do two things:

### 1. Make a discussion sub site. (subject.stackexchange.com/discussion/)

In this world, there is no right, wrong, vote up, down, or rep. Only **pin answer/post**, to point important conclusion and **flag**, in case of off-topic.

### 2. Advanced on-hold

In this 'advanced' version, question that is seems opinion based should be answered with facts as much as possible by people who is good at that subject (Naruto Master, Gravity Master, Logic Master, Harry Potter master, etc). Then, we shall take conclusion whether the conclusion is too wide or narrow enough. From that we can conclude whether it is purely opinion based or only 85% opinion based.

Comment: Your "advanced on-hold" proposal introduces far more complexity with little to no benefit. Questions with bigger problems that no action is taken on are common throughout SE. Who would want to come and answer an opinion-based question "as much as possible"?

Comment: @gnat semi duplicate :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your #1 proposal is already implemented! It is called Chat. There are chat rooms per subject, where you can discuss things. Make sure you get accustomed to the room first. Don't enter the room and spam it immediately.

Your #2 proposal actually still allows unwanted questions on the site. Whether the question *can* be answered is not important, it is just not a subject we want to have. For opinion based questions you have discussion forums, or chat.

Comment: hehe yes i just got my chat room 20 rep today.. now i see.. sorry for this troublesome post hehe

Answer (score 1):

It's not about whether an answer is *actually* available, its about whether there is a theoretical correct answer or not.

*"I can't get X to work - I've tried doing Y but it's not fixing it. What should I do?"* is a question that theoretically has a correct answer. But *"What do you think is the best X"* is not.

You need to be able to ask a question that you have an expectation of what a Correct answer would look like.

- Good: "If someone can give me the correct line of code that'll solve my problem"
- Bad: "If people can give me lots of options I can then pick the one I like best".

Comment: not like lots of opinion. like x+y=3. x+y=2+1 or 1+2. Not many but posibility can be narrowed down into few answer.

Comment: @LordSacha There will always be different ways to achieve a solution, but generally there will be a better way than others. That's what you need. You don't want *lots* of solutions. You want something that solves the problem in the best possible way.

Comment: well you know, sometimes i didnt realize if it has 'lots' of solution.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is:

1. Read the tutorial page for the SE site you are targeting.
2. If in doubt about your question, go to [chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/) or meta, ask the subject-matter experts for help in creating the question.

That's it. This is easier and more practical than an *advanced-discussion-sub-site-where-no-one-downvotes*.

Comment: yes. i just got my 20 rep chat room today. i am rather new. and uneasy with these stuff. sorry for making this trouble some question